# I can not install PyQt and sip_4.13.2 on Windows7 x64. "undefined reference"

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

**I have errors when compiling sip_4.13.2:**

c:\Qt\sip>c:\Python27\python configure.py -p win32-g++

**c:\mingw32-make**

> voidptr.o: voidptr.c: (. text +0 xa09): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCapsule_GetPointer'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   mingw32-make [1]: *** [sip.pyd] Error 1
>   mingw32-make [1]: Leaving directory`C:\Qt\sip\siplib'
>   mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2

**My versions:**

- Windows7_x64
- Python2.7x64(Activestate)
- qt-win-opensource-4.8.0-mingw
- Qt_SDK_Win_offline_v1_2_en

Anyone can help? Thank you.

Comment: You should probably ask this on the [PyQt Mailing List](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).

Comment: Yes! I've asked for help in http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo.

Thank you Jim.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**, thanks to the help of Phil Thompson [PyQt Mailing List](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt)... Solved! My installation was wrong. I'm using the binary installation PyQt*.exe, then it is not necessary to compile the SIP.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am also attempting to use the binary installation of PyQt, but I get this: ```ImportError: No module named sipconfig``` 

Alas, I had no luck finding your message in the PyQt mailing list archive. It's unfortunate we don't have a link to the specific message here.